# validate google docs and office 365 url

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using regex for validating if the provided url is valid or not. To test validity(either google docs url or office 365 docs), I did the following but it's not working

```
var url = "https://hello-my.sharepoint.com/:w:/r/personal/;
var urlRegx = new RegExp('^(docs.google.com|(http|https)://[A-Za-z]-.my.sharepoint.com)', 'i');
console.log(urlRegx.test(url));
```

This is giving me `false` when i have the sharepoint url but `true` when i have the `url = "docs.google.com/document/"

Comment: Try `var urlRegx = /^(?:docs\.google\.com|https?):\/\/[A-Za-z]+-my\.sharepoint\.com/i;`. See [the **regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/b3sqmN/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got an additional closing bracket `)` at the end of your expression which you should remove.

You are also missing a `+` after `[A-Za-z]` (as without the plus you are only matching a single character).

Here is a working example:

```js
var url = "https://hello-my.sharepoint.com/:w:/r/personal/";
var urlRegx = new RegExp('(docs.google.com|(http|https))(://[A-Za-z]+-my.sharepoint.com)?', 'i');
console.log(urlRegx.test(url));
```

**Note:** When using the RegExp constructor you do not need to escape the special characters. Thus, if you don't use the `RegExp` constructor you must escape your special characters like so:

`var urlRegx = /(docs\.google\.com|(http|https)):\/\/[A-Za-z]+-my\.sharepoint\.com/i;`

Comment: You still did not escape dots. See `console.log('\.')`. There is no need escaping `/` in a regex pattern built with RegExp constructor, `/` is not a special regex metacharacter.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ah yes, you right. Thanks for pointing this out. I've updated my answer

Comment: if you try to validate the url 'docs.google.com' it gives you false as an output

Comment: @milan try `new RegExp('(docs.google.com|(http|https))(://[A-Za-z]+-my.sharepoint.com)?', 'i');` instead